# Timer.h library in Arduino, sequence of works

Tags: multithreading, timer, arduino

I'm using the library Timer.h as from [here.](http://www.doctormonk.com/2012/01/arduino-timer-library.html)

Just wondering, as in the example given:

```
#include "Timer.h"

Timer t;
int pin = 13;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(pin, OUTPUT);
  t.oscillate(pin, 100, LOW);
  t.every(1000, takeReading);
}

void loop()
{
  t.update();
}

void takeReading()
{
  Serial.println(analogRead(0));
}
```

In every second, Arduino has to work on oscillating pin 13 and also function takeReading() at the same time/ moment. As Arduino is only [single threading,](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/286/how-can-i-create-multiple-running-threads) I wonder which work goes first? Seems the blog on the library did not state that..

And what if takeReading() is a long function? The oscillation will not be accurate, right?

Answer (score 0):

The source code is available to be read.

The "event clock" is not exactly accurate, time-wise. The module relies on update() being called regularly in the Arduino loop(). If something else is going on in the loop, or if some function busy-waits or delays, then the events will be late.

As to which one gets called first, the events are called in the order they are created. They are essentially in an array of events. The update() function cycles through every event in the array and runs the callback function if enough time has elapsed.

If you want accurate timing, you can always set up interrupts yourself using the other timers. This module seems pretty easy and intuitive to use, though.